# Python: calling class variables and class methods from within __init__ function

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to gain a better understanding of `class variables` and the `@classmethod` decorator in python. I've done a lot of googling but I am having difficulty grasping basic OOP concepts. Take the following class:

```
class Repository:
    repositories = []
    repository_count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.update_repositories()
        Repository.repository_count += 1

    @classmethod
    def update_repositories(cls):
        if not cls.repositories:
            print('appending repository')
            cls.repositories.append('twenty')
        else:
            print('list is full')


a = Repository()
b = Repository()
print(Repository.repository_count)
```

Output:

```
appending repository
list is full
2
```

1. In the `__init__` method, why does `self.update_repositories()` successfully call the `update_repositories` class method? I thought that `self` in this case refers to the instantiated object, not the class?
2. The code works without using the `@classmethod` decorator. Why?
3. In the `__init__` method why do I need to use the keyword `Repository` in `Repository.repository_count += 1`? Am I doing this correctly or is there a better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Class methods can be called from an instance. Look at the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

> A class method can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance (such as C().f()). The instance is ignored except for its class. If a class method is called for a derived class, the derived class object is passed as the implied first argument.

2. The function works without the decorator, but it is not a class method. The `cls` and `self` parameter names are simply convention. You can put anything in the place of `cls` or `self`. For example:

   ```
   class Demo:

       def __init__(self):
           pass

       def instance_method(test):
           print(test)

       @classmethod
       def class_method(test):
           print(test)

   demo = Demo()
   ```

   This results in:

   ```
   demo.instance_method()
   >>> <__main__.Demo object at 0x7facd8e34510>

   demo.class_method()
   >>> <class '__main__.Demo'>
   ```

   So all non decorated methods in a class are a considered **instance**
   methods and all methods decorated with `@classmethod` are
   **class** methods. Naming your parameters `cls`, `self` or
   anything else for that matter does not effect the functionality, but I
   would strongly advice sticking with convention.

   In your case specifcally removing the `@classmethod` decorator turns the method into an instance method and `cls` is now actually what `self` would normally be, a reference to the class's instance. Since class methods and attributes can be called from an instance `cls.update_repositories` still points to the class variable.
3. Depends on what you are trying to do. Generally if you want to access a class variable or method inside a class, but outside a class method, your approach is correct.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up, it definitely helped clarify things.